# SQL Server Dynamic Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having the stored procedure. For that i need to pass the Database name as the paramters from another application or another SP. I know the approach of dynamic SQL, something like,

```
Create procedure mysp(@dbname varchar(20))
as
begin
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql='select * from '+@dbname+'.dbo.table'
end

exec mysp 'mydb'
```

But i dont want the SQL statements as a string. Because in my SP, i have many Sql statements are coming (Not like this only SELECT statement). so can i use,

```
USE DatabaseName
```

inside the stored procedure, so that i can use the db name in the sql statements directly without making it as string. Or any other approach is there. 
My requirements, only for db name, i dont want the entire the sql statement to be dynamic...
please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `USE` instruction to the dynamic query you are creating. Then you can work with that database's tables and other objects without the qualifier (within the dynamic query):

```
Create procedure mysp(@dbname varchar(20))
as
begin
declare @sql varchar(max)
  set @sql='use '+@dbname;
  set @sql=@sql + ';select ... from dbo.table1';
  set @sql=@sql + ';update dbo.table2...';
  set @sql=@sql + ';insert into dbo.table3...';
  ...
  exec(@sql);
end

exec mysp 'mydb'
```

However, while you *can* do that, it's not something that you *should* do, unless you really have to. You are probably trying to avoid creating the same procedure in different DBs, but you may be getting you other problems with this approach, or robbing yourself of some advantages you might otherwise have without resorting to dynamic queries in SPs.

Comment: <code> declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql='USE '+@dbname   </code>
then go ahead with the DML queries... It is working

Comment: @Robin clave: Do you mean that you do that like I've suggested? Or do you only include `USE...` in the dynamic query and the rest of statements are the proper part of the SP?

Answer (score 0):

No, `USE` isn't allowed in stored procedures, functions and triggers.

A stored procedure is supposed to be local to the database. To access another database, there is one way (as far as I know), and it's the one you used.